# migrating data from heroku bucketeer to aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, heroku

I'm just about to get started building and deploying an app on heroku, and to store some media files I'd like to use [Heroku's Bucketeer](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer).

However, thinking that this might be a vendor lock (even though it's AWS s3 under the hood), I looked for data migration guides from bucketeer to S3 (or anywhere), but couldn't find anything.

Anyone out there have experience with this, or can point to some relevant docs?